# Unable to delete row data in my table view from sqlite

Tags: ios, sqlite, uitableview

I am trying to delete the data from my table view.The data is coming from the database.

```
if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {

    DetailData *datatoDelete;//=[DetailData new];
    datatoDelete= dataArray[indexPath.row];

    NSLog(@"ID at  selected row is %@",datatoDelete.ID);


    NSString *docsDir;
    NSArray *dirPaths;

    // Get the documents directory
    dirPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    docsDir = dirPaths[0];

    // Build the path to the database file

    databasePath = [[NSString alloc]
                    initWithString: [docsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:
                                     @"MYDat.db"]];

    const char *dbpath = [databasePath UTF8String];
    sqlite3_stmt    *statement;

    if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &myDatabase) == SQLITE_OK)
    {

        NSString *querySQL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"DELETE FROM ABC WHERE ID=%@",datatoDelete.ID];

    // i tried ID='%@' too

        const char *query_stmt = [querySQL UTF8String];

        if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(myDatabase, query_stmt, -1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)
        {

            NSLog(@"statement deleted successfully"); // i am seeing this statement when i click delete

        }
        sqlite3_finalize(statement);
        sqlite3_close(myDatabase);
    }

 //  [dataArray removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    [tableView reloadData];

}
```

Here when I click on delete, i am getting "the statement data deleted successfully" but,when I check the database file after the delete operation, the data still exists there.Could anyone tell me whats wrong in here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `sqlite3_prepare_v2` only prepares a statement, you need to use `sqlite3_step` for executing it.

```
  if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(myDatabase, query_stmt, -1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)
  {
      if(sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_DONE)
      {
           NSLog(@"statement deleted successfully");
      }
  }
```

For referece:

1. [sqlite_step](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/using-sqlite/9781449394592/re325.html)
2. [Evaluate An SQL Statement](https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/step.html)

Comment: it is giving me the exc_bad_access at the line "if(sqlite3_step(query_stmt) == SQLITE_DONE)"

Comment: @neverStop_coding: that's my bad, typo. please check my edited answer. Use `if(sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_DONE)`

Comment: The data was deleted from database ,but the data still appears on the list view. I tried  [dataArray removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        [self.tableView reloadData];     ,but i couldnt make the data remove from the list view.

Comment: The reload data should do it, are you connected tableview outlet property? Also check whether table view is reloading or not. If yes, check the data is not there in the array

Comment: the data is not there in the array, i guess the table is not reloading properly. Datasource and delegate are connected properly.

Comment: Is table view a outlet? If yes, check that is connected or not.

Comment: no the table view is not an outlet. I used self.tableview.

Comment: @neverStop_coding: are you using UITableViewController ?